# How to change identity when sending email and SMS on AWS SES or SNS

Tags: email, amazon-aws, sms

I use AWS SES and SNS to send email and SMS to users. I want to change the display name and email address of the sender depending on the country of the user. My understanding is that I can create a shared credentials profile, such as:

```
[sms]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...

[sms_US]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
```

and then change the profile in the constructor class:

```
var publish_text_promise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31', profile_name: "sms_US"}).publish(params).promise();
```

On the SNS console, I created a new topic with a different display name. On the SES console, I already created and verified an identity for the other sender email address.

But I don't see how to create a credentials profile that is bound to the different display names. I searched online and read several articles from the AWS docs to no avail.

How can I change the identity of the sender for SMS and email on AWS?